# Does SQL Server have an equivalent to MySql's sql_no_cache modifier?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

In MySql to test performance of an individual query, and take the query cache out of the picture, you can use the sql_no_cache modifier in your select statement:

```
select sql_no_cache * from Foo;
```

Is there a similar per-query option in Microsoft SQL Server? I have seen many posts about using:

```
CHECKPOINT
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

but this seems like overkill and might give SQL Server a disadvantage when trying to compare performance to MySql for the same non-cached query.

Comment: For those of us not familiar with MySQL What does `sql_no_cache` control? Cached execution plan or cached data pages?

Comment: @MartinSmith: `SQL_NO_CACHE` tells MySQL not to store the result in the query cache.

Comment: @eggyal - Oh it actually stores the query result? SQL Server doesn't do that anyway. The execution plan is compiled and cached and pages read in to the buffer pool can benefit subsequent executions but it doesn't cache actual query results.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Indeed it does - see [The MySQL Query Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/query-cache.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a specific query plan from cache, grab the plan handle for your query:

```
SELECT
    t.text,
    s.plan_handle,
    s.creation_time,
    s.last_execution_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats as s
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (s.sql_handle) as t
-- optionally filter based on query text
-- WHERE t.text LIKE '%blah%';
```

SQL Server 2008+ allows passing a plan handle to [`DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx) to remove a specific plan from the cache:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (<plan_handle>);
```

Comment: thanks, that certainly seems to have a small effect on the execution time